# AllowAllHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE issue in Websphere 8.5

Tags: java, http-headers, websphere, websphere-8, apache-commons-httpclient

We are making http url call , but request is not going through. Instead it throws 
below error in Websphere 8.5.

Same code works with Websphere 7 version. Please let me know if there is any difference in making http requests between Websphere 7 and 8/8.5 versions.

```
[7/15/15 12:04:46:581 EDT] 000000c5 SystemOut     O exc2:::null::org/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE
[7/15/15 11:24:04:211 EDT] 0000009b SystemErr     R java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory (initialization failure)
[7/15/15 11:24:04:211 EDT] 0000009b SystemErr     R     at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:175)
[7/15/15 11:24:04:212 EDT] 0000009b SystemErr     R     at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:912)
[7/15/15 11:24:04:212 EDT] 0000009b SystemErr     R     at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients.createDefault(HttpClients.java:58)
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

WAS8.5 ships with its own versions of the Apache HTTP client
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014853459

You might want to try the parent class loading from the server
or try using the IBM jars